# Como o Python determina se um valor é verdadeiro?

Tags: python, operadores, booleano, operador-lógico

Estou com a seguinte dúvida:

```
>>> a = [200,100]
>>> a[True]
```

Saída `>>>` 100

```
>>> a = [200,100]
>>> a[False]
```

Saída `>>>` 200

Por que isso acontece? O primeiro valor é falso e o segundo verdadeiro?

Comment: Isso é uma herança do C, provavelmente. Em C, falso é indicado por `0`, já verdadeiro seria tudo diferente de `0`, muitas vezes convencionado como `1`

Answer (score 7):

Isso ocorre porque `false` é igual a 0 e `true` é igual a 1.

Então seria a mesma coisa que:

```
a = [200,100]
a[1]
```

> Saída >>> 100

```
a = [200,100]
a[0]
```

> Saída >>> 200

Em Python qualquer valor diferente de 0 automaticamente é `true` quando você for fazer alguma verificação lógica, por exemplo:

```
(3 == true) //true
(0 == true) //false
```

Comment: Excelente, muito obrigado pela resposta!